# Entity Framework many-to-many relation with filter in mapping

Tags: entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create a relation using Fluent API, but I can't get it to work. There are 2 tables: SecurityEntities and SecurityEntityRelations. The SecurityEntities table contains users and groups, the SecurityEntityRelation table is an association table that contains relations between the users and groups (it defines which groups contain which members). I already mamaged to relate the 2 entities within EntityTypeConfiguration:

```
        HasMany(se => se.Groups).WithMany(g => g.Members).Map(seg =>
        {
            seg.MapLeftKey("ser_EntityName");
            seg.MapRightKey("ser_MemberOf");
            seg.ToTable("ser_SecurityEntityRelations");
        });
```

This populates the SecurityEntity.Groups and Members properties. But one of the security groups is being concidered a "primary" group, which should be stored in a separate SecurityEntity.PrimaryGroup property. In SQL, this is implemented by a column in the SecurityEntityRelation table, which marks the relation as being "primary". (I know, a self-referencing foreign key in the SecurityEntity table would have been a better solution, but this was designed quite some time ago, and we're stuck with this implementation because our legacy code is also written this way) So, now my question is: how can I create an EF mapping like the one above, which specifies the same relation, but only when column "ser_IsPrimaryGroup" equals a fixed value of '1'?

Comment: Why not just explicitly declare the junction table and add the IsPrimaryGroup property? That's a very common pattern.

Comment: Well, that was my fallback solution. If the entities would be modeled that way, the entities would represent data logic, I would prefer that the entities represent functional logic instead. But if that's not possible then I would have to go with that solution like you said.